# I got src="[object Object]" in img tag when i pass data to ReactQuill

Tags: reactjs, react-quill

In the image tag i got src="[object Object]"

I ouput that data in console and in dom. Everything looks fine. But When i pass that data into ReactQuill component, things get weird and it gets [object Object] in src of image tag.

```
        <Container>
            {article && <>
                {article.content.toString()}
                <br></br>
                {article.content}
            </>}
            <ReactQuill
                ref={(el) => {
                    quillRef = el
                } }
                theme="snow"
                value={article?.content}
                // value={article.content || ''}
                onChange={handleChangeEditor}
                formats={formats}
                modules={modules}
                padding={0}
            />
        <Container/>
```

[image: Here's the result]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

React Quill value supports base64 filetype for an image.Like this you can render. Either you convert your image to base64 format in url.

```
let val='<p><img src="data:image/png;base64,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"></p>'


<ReactQuill
                ref={(el) => {
                    quillRef = el
                } }
                theme="snow"
                value={val}
                // value={article.content || ''}
                onChange={handleChangeEditor}
                formats={formats}
                modules={modules}
                padding={0}
            />
```

Comment: I need to send back with url to the server. Converting into base64 might get another problem when i send to server

Comment: I converted to base 64. But i still got <img src="[object Object]" style="width: 100%">

Comment: Can you check variable val in your ReactQuill Components Once?

Comment: How can I check inise deault ReactQuill component. I update my question with an image. Plz check this above.

Comment: Is it something to do with json data being sent/recieved?